# Using one function in php getting different results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My project includes these files:

1. index.php
2. functions/query.php
3. functions/index.php

Currently running on Xampp. Content inside files:
index.php

```
     <?php
require_once ("functions/query.php");
    $lojrat= lojra();
$decode=json_decode($lojrat, true);
foreach ($decode as $lojra) {

  echo $lojra['L_ID'];


}?>
```

functions/query.php

```
function lojra(){
    global $mysqli;
 $sql="SELECT * FROM `lojrat`";
 $result=$mysqli->query($sql);
 $json=array();
    $num=$result->num_rows;

 while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
       $lojrat[] = array(
    'L_ID' => $row['L_ID'],
    'L_Titulli' => $row['L_Titulli'],
    'L_indextitulli' => $row['L_indextitulli'],
    'L_fotoindex' => $row['L_fotoindex'],
    'L_Embel' => $row['L_Embel'],
    'L_cat' => $row['L_cat'],
    'L_Played' => $row['L_Played']
  );
    }
    $jsonResults = json_encode($lojrat);

    return $jsonResults;

 }
```

functions/index.php

```
  <?php
require_once("query.php");
    $lojrat= lojra();
$decode=json_decode($lojrat, true);
foreach ($decode as $lojra) {

  echo $lojra['L_ID'];

}
```

The problem is when i run that on "index.php" it returns values as 6,5,4,3,2,1 and when i try again the same code in "functions/index.php" i get the result i want 1,2,3,4,5,6...

Problem occurred when i changed sql query to

```
 $sql="SELECT * FROM `lojrat` ORDER BY 'L_ID' DESC";
```

Then switched back to old sql.Is this any XAMPP error because i don't have any live host to test on?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to understand SQL for this. ORDER BY DESC means you will order your result set descending by L_ID column, by default the results are returned as ASC, ascending.

Comment: I know that, the problem is the main index.php file is not using updated query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make **L_ID** as key in **lojra()** function like:

```
 $lojrat[$row['L_ID']] = array( 'L_ID' => $row['L_ID'], 'L_Titulli' => $row['L_Titulli'], 'L_indextitulli' => $row['L_indextitulli'], 'L_fotoindex' => $row['L_fotoindex'], 'L_Embel' => $row['L_Embel'], 'L_cat' => $row['L_cat'], 'L_Played' => $row['L_Played'] );
```

And in both index.php file use as like that:

```
foreach ($decode as $key => $lojra) {

echo $key;

}
```

This will return you **1 2 3 4 5 6** in both cases

Comment: Great now dont forget to mark as accepted answer it will help to other who facing this issue . Just click on the left green tick @bleron

Answer (score 0):

Use backticks if you want to escape a column name. If you use quotation marks, it will be trated as a string instead of a column reference.

You can also use:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM lojrat ORDER BY L_ID DESC";
```

Comment: Indeed you're right regarding the rule you report, but I guess it's not the problem here. Rather probably a typo in the question, while correctly written in his real try, since he gets the exected descending order for one the instances.